# Spring and Hibernate injection in other class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new in subject

I have the configuration

And try to inject it

```
@Controller 
public class HelloController {
    @Autowired
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public @ResponseBody String save() throws Exception {
       hibernateTemplate.save(new Some(Long.valueOf("33"), Integer.valueOf("1"), Double.valueOf("1"), Short.valueOf("0")));    
    }
}
```

it work.

But if i try to use @Autowired in other class i have NPE
example

```
public class SomeFacade extends AbstractFacade<Some> {

    @Autowired
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Override
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

}
```

and use it in

```
@Controller 
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public @ResponseBody String save() throws Exception {
        SomeFacade df = new SomeFacade();
        HibernateTemplate ht = df.getHibernateTemplate();
    }
}
```

And i have "ht" is Null

I don't know what happen in that code and why it's not work, i think it because my class not register in xml file.
Please help with that example.
Thank You!

Comment: Yes, for this to work, SomeFacade would need to be a Spring bean, and would need to be injected into HelloController - instead of HelloController constructing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @GreybeardedGeek said it need to be a Spring bean. You can added the @Component annotation to your class so it will be managed by spring :

```
@Component
public class SomeFacade extends AbstractFacade<Some> {

    @Autowired
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Override
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

}
```

Don't forget to add the component-scan in your xml file (root context) if it is not already there :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package" />
```

If you are using this solution, inject the component instead of using the new keyword :

```
@Controller 
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeFacade df;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public @ResponseBody String save() throws Exception {
        HibernateTemplate ht = df.getHibernateTemplate();
    }
}
```